# list.files returns character(0), why?

Tags: r

I am in my working directory which has 6-7 different files. When I type `list.files()` I get `character(0)`. I can load the files (e.g. `readcsv("fiile1.csv"))`. Also, `file.exists("file1.csv")` returns `TRUE`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit:
After a bit of searching I realized that the problem is with my One Drive.
So I have two Hard Drives (C and E). In E I have two one drive folders (personal and university). I can set the working directory and find all files with `list.files()` anywhere in my PC except my university one drive. When I try to set my working directory in a subfolder of one drive I get the error `Error in setwd("blablabla") cannot change working directory`. I even closed the One Drive up in case this is the problem but still nothing...
I think the problem might be the name of the folder (OneDrive - Kormanyzati Informatikai Fejlesztesi Ugynokseg), but I cannot understand why. In MATLAB I can set working directories and list files without problems.

Comment: Maybe the files are invisible? You could try `list.files(all.files = TRUE)`.

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried that, It didn't work

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? I am running into the same thing. I have worked with this directory regularly and use the same script weekly... this is the first time I've run into the issue.

Comment: In my case the problem was that the path name was too long.